# Encapsulation over engineering

Tags: java, design-patterns, encapsulation

In the `doJob()` method, B is referenced through getter. I personally do not favor this idea and would prefer  just `b.execute()`  since I know for sure that `getB()` will never be modified.

I know that by doing this, would be moving away from encapsulation, but isn't encapsulating B object an overkill here?

```
class A{
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b){
         this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB(){
         return b;
    }

    public void doJob(){
       getB().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the class you don't have to worry about using `getB()`, since `b` is a `private` variable defined inside your class. However, once you try to access it from another class, you will need to use the getter.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181567/should-the-methods-of-a-class-call-its-own-getters-and-setters

Comment: When you state "*`getB()` will never be modified*", enforce this by writing `final` to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter if you access `B` through its attribute or getter as long as the attribute remains `private` (so yes, calling `getB()` is an overkill, it certainly doesn't break any design pattern).

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario it's probably overkill because it's a simple object.  But what if there was lazy loading and your object looked like this..

```
class A{
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b){
         this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB(){
         this.b = this.b ?? new B();
         return this.b;
    }

    public void doJob(){
       getB().execute();
    }
}
```

Then it's not overkill to access your private members via a property.

I don't know if this will help you, but if B is a dependency then your object should be setup like this where IB is the interface of the concrete object B.  It's an inversion of control pattern to decouple the concrete object B from A.  But this is overkill for simple object graphs as well

```
class A{
    private IB b;

    // Use inversion of control
    public A(IB b){
         this.b = b;
    }

    public IB getB(){
         return this.b;
    }

    public void doJob(){
       getB().execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found this lazy loader pattern especially useful when information is expensive to recreate, invalidated often and used occasionally. If its invalidated I just flip a boolean to say its dirty and the next time its needed its recalculated. But it may be invalidated many times before that though, saving me all those unnessisary recalcs

Comment: When objects are created they should be 99% of the time in a valid state.  This is a heavily debated argument though.  I tend to lean towards keeping my objects in a valid state, but others argue that objects should be able to be saved in an invalid state.  For example, if a user is filling out a user profile, then they should be able to save that user profile in any state  and continue later.  I argue that they have a fundamental flaw in their design if there domain model is exposed at the client.  There are special objects to expose to the client (DTO's or ViewModels).

Comment: I would say they must always be in an **externally** valid state

Comment: agreed.  externally definitely and internally most of the time.

Comment: Am using a framework that injects B into A and there is no way the framework would allow a null injection. Even with dependency injection why do we have to use getB().execute() ?

Comment: If B can be null then it's not a dependency.  Without inversion of control (IOC), you would instantiate the dependencies (B) in the constructor of (A).  This means that the object (A) cannot be valid without it's dependencies (B). Dependency inject and IOC allow the instantiation of B to be performed outside of the object A, but concept is the same.  A cannot be valid unless B is instantiated, hence a dependency.  If B can be null, then B shouldn't be instantiated inside the constructor or instantiated  via IOC.  You can still inject B via property injection.

Comment: getB().execute()...I have no idea what that is.  It's just an example.  I wouldn't think about it too hard

Comment: @user1339772 It will be useful if the class is not constructor injected, but parameter injected. Parameter injected is commonly bad, but it gives you ability to navigate through the classes / code, in which very useful for programmers without dependency injection knowledge.

Comment: @DennisFlagg For your 2nd example, I think it will be better if you return concrete class instead of interface in the `getB()` method (unless I misuderstand your point). Maybe it will be better if `getIBAsConcreteB()`. Even though still a code smell for me.

Comment: Returning an interface is better.  It allows the concrete class of B to change to say concrete class C.  As long as class C implements the same interface as B, then the level of effort in maintenance is minimal. For example if a method returns an ICollection then the underlying concrete object can either be List or HashSet or another object that implements ICollection.  You might wonder why would you change it...well say you were trying to improve performance and you changed the underlying object from List to HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

You are minimizing risk by using the getter. What if it turns out the `B` was `null` in one use case or you need to initialize `B` because of a new requirement. This pattern allows you to update `getB()` without having to change anything else in `A`.

```
public B getB(){
   if(b == null) {
       b = getEntityManger().findB(); // or wherever you wanted to get B from
   }

   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is ok only if you make the whole class, or at least make the setter and getter, `final`.

Otherwise this breaks:

```
class A2 extends A {

    private B2 b;

    @override
    public void setB(B b){
         this.b = new B2(b);
    }

    @override
    public B getB(){
         return b.toB();
    }
}
```

Now calling the non-overriden `doJob()` will use wrong member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Providing accessor/mutator methods for a private member enables you to add error checking, change the storage of the member, and do other things internal to the class.  How you access the member within the class is your choice.

If you discover you need to change the class internals later, then switching to the accessor/mutator can be done then.  Certainly this simple example does not require the accessor (getter) method.  But realize that a more complex case might benefit by using the getter.